# PHP Variable In Link

Tags: php

Here is the part of my script I need help with, the PHP Variable works, just not for the links.

```
$source_file = 'http://domain.tld/subfolder/<?php echo $_GET["m"]; ?>".png';
```

It doesn't work. When the script runs, it runs it as , instead of what was typed in for the m value, however when I have this not in a link, it works just fine. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code (when corrected) may contain or be a vector for a [cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) vulnerability.  **Never** pass unfiltered user-provided data in a URL or as part of an HTTP header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using single quotes, PHP takes the literal value. You can use this:

```
$source_file = 'http://domain.tld/subfolder/' . $_GET["m"] . '.png';
```

Comment: More accurately, he is not using php's concatenation and instead expecting open php tags to parse correctly even if already in php. Even in non literal, his code would have failed.

Comment: Thank you. I will mark you as the correct answer once it lets me in 12 Minutes. I knew this would be a simple fix, I just couldn't find anything on it.

Comment: @user1869381 I would recommend taking a couple minutes to read about [how strings work in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
$source_file = 'http://domain.tld/subfolder/' . $_GET["m"] . '.png';
```

You are already in PHP code so you must not reopen `<?php` tags but concatenate each part of the string

Answer (score 0):

You have an errant `"` after the `?>`.

Aside from that, just toss the var in there directly:

```
$source_file = "http://domain.tld/subfolder/$_GET[m].png";
```

I prefer this to using `.` and doing unnecessary concatenations.

Cheers